# Why does Console.WriteLine() not print a string and an int together

Tags: c#

I have a problem with `Console.WriteLine()` in C#. It just doesn't display `string` and `int` variables together.

It just shows the `string` and not the `int`, it mentions something about string format that i don't understand how to fix and that didn't happen to me before.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace FirstStep
{
    class Program11
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 2;
            int b = 4;

            Console.WriteLine(" summ up to Digits ");
            Console.WriteLine("Here there are",a+b);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: string number1 = "1"; int number2 = 2; Console.WriteLine("This is number one {0}, this is number two {1}.", number1, number2.ToString());

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to provide the placeholder for that sum calculation

```
Console.WriteLine("Here there are {0}",a+b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need specific format information like placeholder,

```
Console.WriteLine("Here there are {0}",a+b);
```

or

You can use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) to print integer with string,

```
Console.WriteLine($"Here there are {a+b}");
```

[From MSDN:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

> String interpolation provides a more readable and convenient syntax to
>   create formatted strings than a string composite formatting feature.

Answer (score 0):

With C# 6, you can now use the hybrid solution:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Hi {a+b} ");
```

This is referred to as string interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

it is simple:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace FirstStep
{
    class Program11
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 2;
            int b = 4;
            //define c 
            int c=a+b;
            Console.WriteLine(" summ up to Digits ");
            //here append c
            Console.WriteLine("Here there are"+c);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

    }
}
```